# StopRecordAsync archive media sink callback

Tags: uwp, video-capture

What callback is sent to an archive sink to indicate recording has stopped when the StopRecordAsync is executed?  I do not see a stop clock or shutdown call on the sample code.

Comment: It seems like `StopRecordAsync()` method will help you stop recording to the archive sink. It indicate the recording has stopped. So could I ask what things you actually needed and why you needed?

Comment: I am writing a custom archive sink and the sink needs to know when to stop and finalize.  I get the presentation clock start, but no presentation clock stop or shutdown callback when StopRecordAsync called by client.  What do I need to use to tell me when to stop?